# How do I create my own ceiling function in Python?

Tags: python

How do I create a ceil() function in Python without using loops or using the "math" library? (In Beginners class, no advanced libraries are allowed)?

I want to make ceil function that contains just one attribute, the number which I want to convert.
Please help!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `doesn't work for all integers`. A ceil function takes a float and rounds to an integer. If you pass it an integer, one would expect it to return that same integer. What are you passing into your `ceil` function? (it would really help if you showed us what you've tried).

Comment: Whart are `a` and `b`? `ceiling` only takes 1 argument.

Comment: My function consumes 2 integers, I divide integer1 by integer 2. and teh result I get should be rounded up.

Answer (score -1):

This simple function seems to work

```
def ceil(x):
    decimal=x%1 #get fractional part of input
    if decimal > 0: #round up if fractional part >0
        return (x-decimal)+1
    else: #input was an integer => no rounding
        return x
```